# Is there way to transfer images to a directory in an IoT edge device using Node-JS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-iot-greengrass

I have been working on a Node-JS application that requires uploading an image to a Amazon-S3 bucket for and then being inferenced using ML on IoT Edge devices running remotely and uploading the inference data on the cloud as a part of my internship. However if I want to directly run the inference when the edge device is available locally connected to my network , I can't find a way to do so. Technically I want to transfer the image to a directory dpu_models/images/ in the local edge device , run some command that will trigger the same inference as it happens on uploading image to AWS-S3.

Comment: "However if I want to directly run the inference when the edge device is available locally connected to my network" - Running inference on edge devices are kind asking for trouble. What kind of operating system you have on your device? What is its capability?

Comment: @qkhanhpro It is using linux as OS. The inferencing already works when fetching images from AWS bucket online , I want make this process happen locally when the edge device is available in local network without any AWS upload involved.